# Positioning a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a div that I want to position relative to the mouse when hovering a span element.
This code is here and it does not seem to work. The div is only displaying.

```js
var x;
var y;
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;
});

$('#sp').hover(function() {
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.display='';
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.position='absolute';
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.left=x;
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.top=y;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sp_info" style="display:none">
  <p>Text that should move with mouse position</p>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
   <td class="active"><center><span id="sp">Here is a test hovering test</span></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you have any idea, please let me know about it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are mixing javascript and jquery?

Comment: I don't really know how it should be otherwise. Is it $('#sp_info').style.position("absolute"); ?

Comment: append `px` at the end, like this `x + 'px'`, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w694pk4r/)

Comment: This isn't moving with this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments inline in the code:

```
// On mousemove on #sp element
$('#sp').mousemove(function(e) {

    // Get the current mouse positions
    var x = e.pageX,
        y = e.pageY;

    // Update the position of `#sp_info` dynamically
    $('#sp_info').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': y + 5, // Leave some margin
        'left': x + 5, // Leave some margin
        'display': 'block'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#sp_info').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kskf71ha/)

Comment: Works fine, going to set it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
var y;
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;

  $('#sp').hover(function() {
    $("#sp_info").css({position:"absolute", left:x, top:y});
  });

});
```

Use jQuery's `css function`. Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x;
var y;
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.display='';
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.position='absolute';
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.left=x+'px';
  document.getElementById('sp_info').style.top=y+'px';
});

$('#sp').hover(function() {
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sp_info" style="display:none">
  <p>Text that should move with mouse position</p>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
   <td class="active"><center><span id="sp">Here is a test hovering test</span></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `left` and `top` in hover event

```js
$('#sp').hover(function(event) {
  $('#sp_info').show().css({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: event.pageX,
    top: event.pageY,
  });
}, function() {
  $('#sp_info').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sp_info" style="display:none">
  <p>Text that should move with mouse position</p>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td class="active">
        <center><span id="sp">Here is a test hovering test</span>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```